# How to concatenate large numbers of GRIB2 files?

Tags: unix, cat, grib

I am currently working with folders full of GRIB2 files, each representing different time periods, and have been concatenating them 1 by 1 in Unix as follows:

cat file1 file2 file3 ... filen combinedfile

However, I am starting to work with a much larger "n" (multiple thousands) and that technique is no longer feasible. Has anyone had experience with a similar issue?

Comment: What is your usage pattern? Do you need to read data fast in the time dimension?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards.

cat infile* > outfile

I had individual GRIB files for each date and the above command concatenated the data according to the dates.

cat U_2014*.grb > U_2014.grb (U_2014.grb had all the 365 days)